# Modifying a cv::Rect inside a cv::Mat in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm pretty new to openCV and would like to ask what seems like a easy question.
I have an image in the form of a `cv::Mat` and I would like to change only a small part of the matrix. I've read that using a `cv::Rect` is the correct way but I can't seem to find a way to only modify that little ROI.

Here's the code:

```cpp
cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::zeros(msg->height, msg->width, CV_64FC1);
cv::Rect rect(100, 100, 20, 50);
```

All I want to do is do linear tranformation to the `rect` and add asign it to the same part of the img.

Something like:

```cpp
int a=0.1, b=20;
rect = rect*a + b;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to modify the pixels in that rect, or do you want to change the rect (to increase and shift it)? First is done by img(rect) = img(rect*0.1); img(rect) = img(rect)+20;

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I want to modify the pixels in that rect. So the image shoud change.

Comment: With img(rect) you get a header to a subimage of that full image and its pixel memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV's [`cv::Mat`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) has a [constructor](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa7ec97373406215f2d4bc72cc1d27036) that creates an ROI image referncing another image:

```
cv::Mat::Mat(const Mat & m, const Rect & roi)
```

Using this constructor will cause the new `cv::Mat` to **share the data** with the original one:

> No data is copied by these constructors. Instead, the header pointing to m data or its sub-array is constructed and associated with it.
> The reference counter, if any, is incremented.
> So, when you modify the matrix formed using such a constructor, you also  modify the corresponding elements of m.

You can also use the [`operator()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4272fce43d7405603fbb5e5f52580e57) for that:

```
Mat cv::Mat::operator() (const Rect & roi)  const
```

In your case you can do something like the following:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

int main()
{
    int h = 320;
    int w = 640;
    cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::ones(h, w, CV_64FC1);
    cv::Rect rect(100, 100, 20, 50);
    cv::Mat roi(img, rect); // alternatively you can use:  cv::Mat roi = img(rect);
    double a = 0.1;
    double b = 20;
    roi = roi * a + b; // this will modify the relevant area in img
    return 0;
}
```